# Geo-Referencing level 1 AQUA data

Tags: modis

I have a direct broadcast AQUA data. I used RT-STPS to extract the level 0 .PDS files and process them further to level 1A and level 1B using the modisL1DB software. These produce .hdf files.

I can view the images however, they are not geo-referenced. How can I geo-referenced these data?

Comment: Do you have access to specialized software like ENVI, or are you looking for an open source solution?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov thanks for the reply. I don't have access to specialized software so I want an open source solution.